# Sending mail from java application deployed in AWS Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jakarta-mail

I get this exception when I am sending an email from my java application deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk running Tomcat server. What am I missing here?

```
06 Jun 2016 17:24:39 [taskExecutor-6] [] ERROR: o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.provider.certpath.AdaptableX509CertSelector
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.isWorthTrying(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:231)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:171)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:279)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:345)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:260)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1454)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:213)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1035)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:503)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:443)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1647)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:534)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:397)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:346)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:341)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(MailSendingMessageHandler.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:260)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:241)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:205)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:199)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:260)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:241)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:205)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:199)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.access$000(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:48)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher$1.run(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The email provided is Office 365. There is no issue with the smtp host name, port. I am able to send emails fine from localhost. Issue is only in AWS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [edit] your question to include what you've written in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Either Beanstalk has a messed up JDK installation/configuration, or there's something in the certificate from the server that's confusing the JDK.  Possibly some firewall or anti-virus is interfering with the connection.

One of the [workarounds described in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert) might help.

- Install the server's certificate into your trust store.
- Set the `mail.smtp.ssl.trust` property to trust the server.